# Erro "OutOfMemoryError" usando Volley

Tags: java, android, json, cache, volley

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde tenho uma URL que retorna um JSON, através da biblioteca Volley, estou pegando o conteúdo dessa URL e transformando em *string*, esse processo é executado a cada *5* segundos, após um certo período minha aplicação gerou o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError   at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:322)
>   at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:540)
>   at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:562)
>   at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:403)
>   at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:156)
>   at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)

O que eu posso fazer para resolver isso?

Estou usando o método `GET RequestQueue` da biblioteca Volley.

Comment: Isso está parecendo um *leak* de memória. Poderia analisar o monitor de memória (isso no Android Studio)? Outra coisa, poderia incluir o código que faz esse request?